# "Adding" dictionaries in python if some (key, value) pairs match

Tags: python, dictionary

Three dictionaries:

```
d0 = {"a": "hello", "b": "world", "c": 11}
d1 = {"a": "hello", "b": "world", "c": 100}
d2 = {"a": "goodbye", "b": "world", "c": 10}
```

They should be placed in a list of dictionaries that I iteratively add to.

```
dictionaries = [d0]
```

How do you merge dictionaries and add the integer "c" values together iff "a" and "b" are the same (str) values?

Hopeful result:

```
d3 = {"a": "hello", "b": "world", "c": 111}
d2 = {"a": "goodbye", "b": "world", "c": 10}
dictionaries = [d2, d3] # any order
```

Comment: Same way would add anything to a list. Either `dictionaries[index]=d2` or use `.append(item)`. For example: `dictionaries.append(d2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collect your `c` values into a dictionary keyed by the `a, b` keys; using a [`collections.defaultdict()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) makes this a little easier:

```
from collections import defaultdict

keyed = defaultdict(int)

for d in (d0, d1, d2):
    keyed[(d['a'], d['b'])] += d['c']

dictionaries = [{'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c} for (a, b), c in keyed.items()]
```

The `keyed` `defaultdict` object defaults to `0` if a specific key is not yet part of the dictionary (calling `int` produces `0`). The above loop then sums all values for `'c'` for a given combination of the `'a'` and `'b'` values.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d0 = {"a": "hello", "b": "world", "c": 11}
>>> d1 = {"a": "hello", "b": "world", "c": 100}
>>> d2 = {"a": "goodbye", "b": "world", "c": 10}
>>> keyed = defaultdict(int)
>>> for d in (d0, d1, d2):
...     keyed[(d['a'], d['b'])] += d['c']
... 
>>> keyed
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {('hello', 'world'): 111, ('goodbye', 'world'): 10})
>>> [{'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c} for (a, b), c in keyed.items()]
[{'a': 'hello', 'c': 111, 'b': 'world'}, {'a': 'goodbye', 'c': 10, 'b': 'world'}]
```